# Two divs inside one div responsive with padding

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I am trying to use padding in my CSS so that the two divs inside my div are responsive at 50% each. But together they obviously are bigger than 100%. I know this is probably the paddings fault, but I don't know how to fix it.
CSS:

```
.columns {
max-width:100%;
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
text-align:left;
}
.col1 {
width:50%;
float:left;
padding-left:100px;
}
.col2 {
width:50%;
float:right;
padding-right:100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="col1">
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the box model will use padding and border to expand an element beyond a specified width. To keep the paddings/borders from pushing outward, and contain them inward, use `box-sizing: border-box;`

```css
.columns {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.col1 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.col2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.col1,
.col2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="col1">
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In situations like these, it's useful to put this rule at the beginning of your styles:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

It sets everything to `box-sizing: border-box;`, which means that the borders and paddings are included in the width/height settings, i.e. a container with width: 200px, border: 1px and padding 10px will really be 200px wide, including borders and padding (and *not* 222px, as it would be without `box-sizing: border-box`).